# undefined reference with member functions using g++

Tags: c++, templates, reference, g++, undefined

For some reasons, sometimes when I define my member functions in a CPP file rather than within their declaring header, I get undefined reference errors from g++.
This question is similar to [Undefined Reference To Member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206633/undefined-reference-to-member-function) but that user managed to solve the problem by adding the missing file to his command line, which doesn't seem to be working here.
Btw, I'm not against using a makefile; in fact I plan to do so eventually, whenever I get used to these commands.

my main file ('ringbuftest.cpp'):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "ringbuffer.h"
using namespace std;

void *reader(void* param);
void *writer(void* param);

struct pack{
  char msg[256];
};

RINGBUFFER<pack> *ringo;

int main(){
pthread_t rdr;
pthread_t wtr;

ringo = new RINGBUFFER<pack>(12);

int ret1 = pthread_create(&rdr,NULL,reader,(void*)NULL);
int ret2 = pthread_create(&wtr,NULL,writer,(void*)NULL);

#ifdef _unix
cout<< "unix single underscore\n";
#elif defined __unix
cout<< "unix two underscores\n";
#endif

pthread_join(wtr,NULL);
pthread_join(rdr,NULL);

cout<< "threads are done\n";
exit(0);
return 0;
}

void *reader(void *param){
  pack myPack;
  while(true)
  {
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){int k=0;k=i;k++;i=k;i--;}
    if( ringo->Pop(&myPack) )
    {
      cout<< myPack.msg;
    }
  }
}
void *writer(void *param){
  pack myPack;
  while(true){
    strcpy(myPack.msg,"hello reader!\n");
    ringo->Push(&myPack);
  }
}
```

my class header ('ringbuffer.h'):

```
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

#ifndef __ring_buffer_h__
#define __ring_buffer_h__

#define RINGBUFFER_DEFAULT_SIZE 8

template <class T>
class RINGBUFFER
{
private:
    unsigned int top;
    unsigned int bottom;
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int count;
    void *items;
public:
    RINGBUFFER();
    RINGBUFFER(unsigned int size);
    ~RINGBUFFER();
    bool Push(T *value);
    bool Pop(T *value);
};


#endif
```

my class definitions ('ringbuffer.CPP'):

```
#include "ringbuffer.h"

template<class T>
RINGBUFFER<T>::RINGBUFFER()
{
    top = bottom = 0;
    size = RINGBUFFER_DEFAULT_SIZE;
    count = 0;
    items = malloc((size+1)*sizeof(T));
}

template<class T>
RINGBUFFER<T>::RINGBUFFER(unsigned int _size)
{
    top = bottom = 0;
    size = _size;
    count = 0;
    items = malloc(size*sizeof(T));
}

template<class T>
RINGBUFFER<T>::~RINGBUFFER()
{
    free(items);
}

template<class T>
bool RINGBUFFER<T>::Push(T *value)
{
    if( count<size )
    {
        memcpy(&(((T*)items)[bottom]),value,sizeof(T));
        bottom = (bottom+1)%size;
        count++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template<class T>
bool RINGBUFFER<T>::Pop(T *value)
{
    if( count>0 ) 
    {
        memcpy(value,&(((T*)items)[top]),sizeof(T));
        top = (top+1)%size;
        count--;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

To compile, I've been trying to use:

```
g++ ringbuffer.CPP ringbuftest.cpp -lpthread -o ringbuffertest.o
```

and I get the errors:

```
/tmp/ccj8RqhY.o: In function `main':
ringbuftest.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `RINGBUFFER<pack>::RINGBUFFER(unsigned int)'
/tmp/ccj8RqhY.o: In function `reader(void*)':
ringbuftest.cpp:(.text+0x157): undefined reference to `RINGBUFFER<pack>::Pop(pack*)'
/tmp/ccj8RqhY.o: In function `writer(void*)':
ringbuftest.cpp:(.text+0x1db): undefined reference to `RINGBUFFER<pack>::Push(pack*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with g++ because I keep hitting this problem in different projects, or maybe I'm using templates wrong.(?)
How can I resolve this error?

Edit:
I should mention that this compiles perfectly if I instead paste the member definitions into the header file and exclude the .CPP from the g++ command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ undefined reference to template class method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914129/c-undefined-reference-to-template-class-method)

Comment: Also don't use `-lpthread`. Use `-pthread` instead. (Unless you have a very good reason not to.)

Comment: Do not put double underscores in your include guards, all names with double underscores are reserved for the implementation. Do not put `using namespace` in a header. Your include guards should be at the top of the file, not after the `#include` and the very naughty `using`. Finally, naming a class template in ALL_CAPS is weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the entire definition of `RINGBUFFER<T>` from `ringbuffer.cpp` to `ringbuffer.h` so that it's visible when `ringbuftest.cpp` is being compiled.

Comment: is this specific to template classes? I had this same error on a non-template class until I rearranged the order of files on the compile command, into order of dependency.